# How to add API description in Swashbuckle?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, api, swagger, swashbuckle

I'm new in Swashbuckl or Swagger but I've created a Web API which requires to create Documentation using Swagger from my client. I've already created but they require the API version details to be shown into the Swageer UI which I'm not so sure how to achieve.

Here is my code:

```
public class SwaggerConfig
{
    public static void Register()
    {
        var thisAssembly = typeof(SwaggerConfig).Assembly;

        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration
            .EnableSwagger(c =>
                {
                    c.SingleApiVersion("v1", "Demo Api");
                    c.IncludeXmlComments(string.Format(@"{0}\bin\WebApi.XML",
                                         System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory));
                })
        .EnableSwaggerUi();

    }
}
```

Controller Example:

```
     /// <summary>
    /// Get the Next IdKey
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>Get the Next IdKey from Dettagli Table</remarks>
    /// <response code="404">Not found</response>
    /// <response code="500">Internal Server Error</response>
    [HttpGet]
    public int GetNextIdDettagli()
    {
        try
        {
            DettagliRepo repo = new DettagliRepo();
            return repo.GetNextIdDettagli();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw (ex);
        }
    }
```

This is how all of the Controller actions has been made.

Here is the output of my Swagger UI:

[image]

This is the expected output from my client marked by 1,2 and 3:

[image]

I can understand from the screen shot that they want API description, title and other information to be shown but I don't know how to show them. please help me or suggest me how do I achieve that part. Thanks in advance.

**Update**

I've achieved 1 and 2 from the [Following link](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle#injecting-custom-content)

with the following code:

```
                   .EnableSwagger(c =>
    {
        c.RootUrl(req => GetRootUrlFromAppConfig());

        c.Schemes(new[] { "http", "https" });

        c.SingleApiVersion("v1", "Swashbuckle.Dummy")
            .Description("A sample API for testing and prototyping Swashbuckle features")
            .TermsOfService("Some terms")
            .Contact(cc => cc
                .Name("Some contact")
                .Url("http://tempuri.org/contact")
                .Email("some.contact@tempuri.org"))
            .License(lc => lc
                .Name("Some License")
                .Url("http://tempuri.org/license"));
    });
```

But still I need help for the point 3. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can actually create a document filter and update the Tags node in the swagger document using the document filter.

See a sample document filter below:

```
public class DocumentFilter : IDocumentFilter
{
    /// <summary>
    /// This method is for applying the filter
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="swaggerDoc">Swagger Document</param>
    /// <param name="schemaRegistry">Schema Registry</param>
    /// <param name="apiExplorer">API Explorer</param>
    public void Apply(SwaggerDocument swaggerDoc, SchemaRegistry schemaRegistry, IApiExplorer apiExplorer)
    {
        var methods = swaggerDoc.paths.Select(i => i.Value);
        List<string> tags = new List<string>();
        foreach (var method in methods)
        {
            if (method.delete != null)
            {
                tags.AddRange(method.delete.tags);
            }

            if (method.get != null)
            {
                tags.AddRange(method.get.tags);
            }

            if (method.put != null)
            {
                tags.AddRange(method.put.tags);
            }

            if (method.post != null)
            {
                tags.AddRange(method.post.tags);
            }

            if (method.patch != null)
            {
                tags.AddRange(method.patch.tags);
            }                
        }

        swaggerDoc.tags = new List<Tag>();
        foreach (var tag in tags)
        {
            swaggerDoc.tags.Add(new Tag() { name = tag, description = "This is a group of methods for " + tag });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much this helped me a lot.